# Converting XML to objects with nested embeded objects

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, visual-studio

I have the following XML which has nested objects and when I want to deserialize the XML into the Steps class with the embedded list of Step objects, I have an error.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="comp")]
public class Comp 
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="ref")]
    public string Ref { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="dir")]
    public string Dir { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="step")]
public class Step 
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="comp")]
    public Comp Comp { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="step")]
    public Step Step { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="steps")]
public class Steps 
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="step")]
    public Step Step { get; set; }
}
```

My XML :

```
<steps>
  <step name="2.3  Upper">
    <step name="2.3.1 Upper">
      <comp ref="15.txt" dir="D:\test" />
      <comp ref="16.txt" dir="D:\test2" />
    </step>
    <step name="2.3.2  Upper" >
      <comp ref="19.txt" dir="D:\test" />
      <comp ref="29.txt" dir="D:\test2" />
    </step>
  </step>
</steps>
```

**Update**: new XML file for more nested step.

```
<steps>
  <step name="2.3  Upper">
    <step name="2.3.1 Upper">
      <step name="2.3.1.1 Upper">
        <comp ref="10.txt" dir="D:\test" />
      </step>
      <comp ref="15.txt" dir="D:\test" />
      <comp ref="16.txt" dir="D:\test2" />
    </step>
    <step name="2.3.2  Upper" >
      <comp ref="19.txt" dir="D:\test" />
      <comp ref="29.txt" dir="D:\test2" />
    </step>
  </step>
</steps>
```

May I ask your help how to get ride of the following error:

> 'Step': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

I am stuck on this error. I really appreciate for your helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's because in your `Step` class:

> ```
> [XmlRoot(ElementName="step")]
> public class Step 
> {
>     [XmlElement(ElementName="comp")]
>     public Comp Comp { get; set; }
>     [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="name")]
>     public string Name { get; set; }
>     [XmlElement(ElementName="step")]
>     public Step Step { get; set; } // <-- Here is your issue
> }
> ```

You have a `Step` within a `Step` called `Step` (inception or what?!).

**EDIT:**

Better suggestion:

Remove the `Steps` class entirely - not needed.

Update your `Step` class, like so:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="step")]
public class Step 
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="comp")]
    public Comp Comp { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="steps")]
    public List<Step> Steps { get; set; }
}
```

**ADDITIONAL EDIT:**

Your XML would then come out like this:

```
<steps>
    <step name="Step 1">
        <steps>
            <!-- 3 substeps in Step 1 -->
            <step name="Step 1 - 1st substep" ></step>
            <step name="Step 1 - 2nd substep" ></step>
            <step name="Step 1 - 3rd substep" >
                <steps>
                    <!-- The 3rd one has its own substep -->
                    <step name="Step 1 - 3rd substep - 1st substep"/>
                </steps>
            </step>
        </steps>
    </step>

    <step name="Step 2">
        <steps>
            <!-- Step 2 has 1 substep -->
            <step name="Step 2 - 1st substep"/>
        </steps>
    </step>

    <step name="Step 3">
        <!-- No substeps in here -->
    </step>
</steps>
```

Obviously your other elements/attributes within the `step` element would include your own, as in your example.

The main point is that the only thing that's changed in the `Step` class is that it can have its own list of `Step`s called `Steps` or `Substeps` (or whatever meaningful name you give).

Comment: But in this way the inner steps when they are more would not be saved in ``Steps``. right?

Comment: I would change your `Steps` object to have a property of type `List<Step>` and you can insert your `Step` objects into this list. If you wanted, your `Step` could also have a `Steps` property inside, to contain more steps (instead of having a single `Step` property). Your hierarchy would be like so: Step > Steps > Step > Steps to go deeper into the tree

Comment: Updated :) There's also no need for your `Steps` class, as you can make a `List<Step>` property inside of the `Step` class. Hierarchy would still be Step > Steps > Step > Steps etc.

Comment: But this order would be correct regarding xml file?

Comment: I would re-think your xml file. Your hierarchy would be something like this: `<step name="1"><steps><step name="1-1"></step><step name="1-2></step></steps></step> Allow each "sub-step" to have its own sub-steps and so-on-and-so-forth

Comment: But this would totally different from what I want to have. because it will destroy all the XML structure.

Comment: Like I said, I would re-think your XML file structure. The way I have suggested is entirely possible and clean; the way you wanted originally is not possible, I'm afraid

Comment: You could try removing the `ElementName="steps"` from the `List<Step>` property - I'm only thinking off the top of my head. You will only find out by trial/error what suits you best

Answer (score 0):

I found out that one could use `List<step>` to have unlimited recursive as follows:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class steps
{
    public script script { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("step")]
    public List<step> step { get; set; }
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class step
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("step")]
    public List<step> Step1 { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("comp")]
    public List<comp> comp { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name { get; set; }
}
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class comp
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string @ref { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string dir { get; set; }
}
```